# How are there two C3 rotation axes in ammonia?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, symmetry

If we look at the character table for the $C_\mathrm{3v}$ point group (which $\ce{NH3}$ is an example of), we see that these are the symmetry elements ${E, 2 C_3, 3 \sigma_v}$ present in the molecule. My question is — why are there $2 C_3$ rotation axes? Shouldn't there be only one, which is perpendicular to the plane containing the three hydrogens?

The $C_\mathrm{3v}$ character table:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{3v} & E & 2C_3 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{v} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\ 
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z &  \\ 
\mathrm{E} & 2 & -1 & 0 & (x,y), (R_x,R_y) & (x^2-y^2,xy), (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: There is indeed only one rotation axis of order 3, and it stands for **two** symmetry elements: rotations by $120^\circ$ and by $240^\circ$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a character table for $C_{3v}$, $ 2C_3$, means that the element is actually 2 $C_3$ elements in the same **conjugacy class**.  That means the two $C_3$ operations are related in some way.

**In fact, it means they share the same single axis.**  One $C_3$ operation is a $120^\circ$ turn around the axis, and the other $C_3$ operation is a $240^\circ$ turn around the same axis in the same direction - or equivalently a $120^\circ$ turn around the same axis in the opposite direction.

In the image below the two elements $C_3$ and $C_3^{-1}$ are the two symmetry elements of the $2C_3$ class, which are rotations about the same axis out of the plain of the image.

[image: Symmetry elements of C3V point group]
Symmetry elements of the $C_{3v}$ point group
Image taken from Fig S5 in supplementary information of [T. Karin, et al, Phys. Rev. B 94, 041201](https://journals.aps.org/prb/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.041201)

Comment: (+1) I guess I would still be careful to make the distinction between a symm. element and a symm. operation — in my experience, at least, the two rotations are the (distinct) operations, and the element is the shared axis — although actually, I'm not sure if this is formalised anywhere better than my Wikipedia link..? (I could look in a book later, though I haven't the time right now.)

Answer (score 14):

The top row of the character table does not refer to *symmetry elements*, but rather *symmetry operations*. (For the difference between the two, see [Wikipedia:Molecular symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_symmetry#Symmetry_concepts).)

In this particular case, the difference is that there is only one $C_3$ symmetry element in ammonia (i.e. the rotation axis), but there are two operations: one corresponds to the clockwise rotation, and the other to the anticlockwise rotation (which is equivalent to two clockwise rotations, should you prefer that).

It is the *symmetry operations*, not the *elements*, which form the so-called "group" in group theory (see [Wikipedia:Group (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics))).

> In mathematics, a group is a set equipped with **a binary operation** that combines any two elements to form a third element in such a way that three conditions called group axioms are satisfied, namely **associativity, identity and invertibility.**

(Emphasis mine.) The "binary operation" for *symmetry operations* is to simply perform one operation after another, which is somewhat akin to composition. Note that the word "element" in the quoted paragraph refers to an abstract member of the group: it is mildly unfortunate that the elements are *symmetry operations*, not symmetry elements.

Comment: What if I prefer two anti-clockwise rotations though? ;)